# Taxonomy terms manipulation on node.tpl.php

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms

I wanted to print taxonomy terms on my custom node-mytype.tpl.php but what I want is not to print all the terms as they are.

Each of these terms consists of 2-3 words. And I want to manipulate the terms as below:

**term1: word1 word2 word3**

I want to print this as:

> word3, word1 word2

If a node has one term it's easy and I can do this as below (of course there can be some other better way to do this):

**inside node-mytype.tpl.php:**

```
<?php if (!empty($node->field_my_taxonomy_term)) { ?>

    <?php $aut = ($node->field_my_taxonomy_term['und']['0']['taxonomy_term']->name); ?>
    <?php $exp = explode(" ", $aut); ?>     

    <?php if (count($exp) == 2) {?>
    <?php print ($exp[1]); print t(", "); print ($exp[0]); print t(", "); ?>

    <?php } elseif (count($exp) == 3) {?>
    <?php print ($exp[2]); print t(", "); print ($exp[0]); print t(" "); print ($exp[1]); print t(", "); ?>
    <?php }?>
```

I want to print multiple terms as above. For example:

**term1: word1 word2 word3**

**term2: word4 word5 word6**

should be printed as that:

> word3, word1 word2 - word6, word4 word5

I have this:

```
   <?php $str = ''; ?>
        <?php if (isset($node->field_my_taxonomy_term[LANGUAGE_NONE]) && $node->field_my_taxonomy_term[LANGUAGE_NONE]): ?>

        <?php foreach ($node->field_my_taxonomy_term[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $obj): ?>
        <?php $str .= l($obj['taxonomy_term']->name, 'taxonomy/term/' . $obj['tid']) . '&nbsp;-&nbsp;'; ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>

        <?php print trim($str, '-&nbsp;'); ?>
   <?php endif ?>
```

The below code prints the terms as that:

> word1 word2 word3 - word4 word5 word6

**What code should I use here to print the terms as I wanted?**

> word3, word1 word2 - word6, word4 word5

*(Drupal 7.34)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I did it as shown below (thanks SO):

```
  <?php if (isset($node->field_my_taxonomy_term[LANGUAGE_NONE]) && $node->field_my_taxonomy_term[LANGUAGE_NONE]): ?>
    <?php $allOf=''?>
    <?php foreach ($node->field_my_taxonomy_term[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $obj): ?>
        <?php $exp = explode (" ", $obj['taxonomy_term']->name);
            $exp_last = array_pop($exp);
            $eachOne = $exp_last .', ' .implode(' ', $exp);
            $allOf .= $eachOne . '&nbsp;-&nbsp;';
         ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php print trim($allOf, '&nbsp;-&nbsp;'); ?>
  <?php endif ?>
```

This is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $str = ''; $terms = array();?>
<?php if (isset($node->field_my_taxonomy_term[LANGUAGE_NONE]) && $node->field_my_taxonomy_term[LANGUAGE_NONE]): ?>

<?php foreach ($node->field_my_taxonomy_term[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $obj): ?>
  <?php $terms[] = $obj;?>
<?php endforeach ?>

<?php 
   $str .= l($term[2]['taxonomy_term']->name, 'taxonomy/term/' . $term[2]['tid']) . ', ';
   $str .= l($term[0]['taxonomy_term']->name, 'taxonomy/term/' . $term[0]['tid']) . ' '; 
   $str .= l($term[1]['taxonomy_term']->name, 'taxonomy/term/' . $term[1]['tid']) . ' - ';
   $str .= l($term[5]['taxonomy_term']->name, 'taxonomy/term/' . $term[5]['tid']) . ', ';
   $str .= l($term[3]['taxonomy_term']->name, 'taxonomy/term/' . $term[3]['tid']) . ' ';
   $str .= l($term[4]['taxonomy_term']->name, 'taxonomy/term/' . $term[4]['tid']) . ' ';
?>

 <?php print trim($str, '-&nbsp;'); ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not I wanted and it gives a lot of error. I think you misunderstood the question because the code you wrote seems to separate the terms not the words inside the terms.

Not all nodes have 2 terms and not all terms have 3 words as I said above. I should do the manipulation for each term separately without knowing have many terms there are in a node.




A node can have 1-10 terms and each term can have 2-3 words.

Node has one 2-words term: **Word2, Word1**

Node has one 2-words term and one 3-words term: **Word2, Word1 - Word5, Word3, Word4**

Comment: The taxonomy vocabulary is author names and on node-mytype.tpl.php I want to print the author names as that: Surname, Name MiddleName - Surname, Name MiddleName - ...

Comment: @herci what happens when your author's surname has more than one word eg. de Beauvoir, van der Velde, le Blanc etc?

Comment: @murraybiscuit, in the case the surnames are always one word.