# How to reference existing term if it exists or create new one if not exist via Inline Entity Form module?

Tags: 7, entities, taxonomy-terms

I have a content type **book** and it has a taxonomy term reference field: `author`.

I want to enter **name** and **surname** separately for each author on **node add/edit** page. Name and surname **together** will be the taxonomy term.

If I enter John for the name and Smith for the surname the taxonomy term will be John Smith.

[image]

I'm [doing](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/193046/how-to-create-a-name-surname-structure-for-taxonomy-terms) this by using the [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) module with the [Automatic Entity Label](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel) module.

The problem here is: the Inline Entity Form has **two** options while entering the term:

1. `Add new term`
2. `Add existing term`.

[image]

If you don't know if the term **exists or not** it become useless.

### What I need is only one option and if the entered `[name + surname]` **exist** then **select** it as author automatically and if that **not exist** **create** a new term.

How can I do this?

*(Similar structure **can be created** with some different methods such as [References Dialog](https://www.drupal.org/project/references_dialog) module, [Entity Connect](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityconnect) module etc but the main problem exist there too.)*

---

**Note**: This question is not a duplicate of "[How to create a name-surname structure for taxonomy terms?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/193046/)" ... even though they use the same image. In this question the main point is "how to combine creating new term and choosing existing one options", in the other question "how to create a name-surname structure on node form" is asked.

Comment: I used to autocomplete deluxe for this but not sure about how it works with inline entity form. https://www.drupal.org/project/autocomplete_deluxe Worked really well.

Comment: @NiallMurphy, I used this module for another project. It doesn't do what I want. Thanks.

Comment: Are Name and Surname also taxonomy fields? Regular fields?

Comment: How is this question different from this one? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/193046/how-to-create-a-name-surname-structure-for-taxonomy-terms

Comment: @Kevin, no name and surname are regular fields.

Comment: @StefanosPetrakis, in the question you mentioned I asked how to create a name-surname structure for taxonomy terms and got the answer. This question is different, I asked here how to solve the "create new" and "add existing one" problem.

Comment: If you got the answer, you should accept it I believe. Regarding the difference, on account of "Questions may be duplicates if they have the same (potential) answers. This includes not only word-for-word duplicates, but also the same idea expressed in different words.", I still believe it's a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, I should accept the other one. But other "answer" doesn't answer this question.

Comment: Ok, would be great to see it accepted, I believe it answered that other question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36571/discussion-between-stefanos-petrakis-and-herci).

Answer (score 2):

This solution is a bit "out there" so I'll just describe the logic.

1. Three taxonomy fields. One for first name, one for last name (so there's autocomplete), one for full name generated by rules.
2. On node save, join the first+last as tokens and fetch term by property name. This will give a list containing one or no terms.
3. Two rules components that receive the list.
4. No. 1: condition, list is empty. Actions. Create term and send it back to the rule.
5. No. 2: condition, list is not empty. Actions. Send back the fetched term.
6. In the main rule, set data value on node, returned terms.

It's "out there" but that's because there are two fields for one term.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but to be honest I couldn't get the point, how to implement this.