# How can I pass values to Rules?

Tags: 7, rules, tokens

I would like to pass values to Rules (eg an array of words) and then do some Rules magic with them (eg create new nodes if they dont exist already).

I found one solution here [How to reference existing term if it exists or create new one if not exist via Inline Entity Form module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/193129/how-to-reference-existing-term-if-it-exists-or-create-new-one-if-not-exist-via-i)
that mentions creating custom tokens. Looks like the token approach can be involving as per https://www.drupal.org/node/1143842, although there is this module as well [Custom Tokens](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_custom).

Would there be any other way? Perhaps calling a url, and passing the values as GET variables or adding entity properties?

Comment: Have you looked at adding custom php code as part of the action?  Would that help?

Comment: I want that as the last resort. Using the php module is a nightmare to debug. I was just thinking about using entity property info.

Comment: As an aside, it's really not that difficult to debug if you have the right IDE.

Comment: Where is the "array of words" coming from? Knowing the source of values that you would like to pass to the rule would help in suggesting a viable solution.

Comment: Frankly anywhere except Drupal :) Plain PHP code, or a json feed.